# Functions and Local Variables in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing an ATM program for a class project, and we're not allowed to use global variables. I used only local variables in my program, but it doesn't work.

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the ATM program!\nThis program allows you to deposit, withdraw, or view your balance!")

def menu():
    print("1...Deposit\n2...Withdraw\n3...View Balance")
    userChoice = int(input("Please enter your choice now: "))
    if userChoice == 1:
        def deposit(balance):
            deposit = float(input("Please enter the amount you would like to deposit: "))
            balance = balance + deposit
    elif userChoice == 2:
        def withdraw(balance):
            withdraw = float(input("Please enter the amount you would like to withdraw: "))
            balance = balance + withdraw
    else:
        def balance(balance):
            print("Your balance is", balance)

        deposit()
        withdraw()
        balance()
welcome()
menu()
```

When I run it, it just ends after I input a choice from the menu without any error messages.

Comment: Do not define functions within `if/else` statements unless you plan to call them right there (though even then I would not define them there).

Comment: Though it is easy to significantly refactor your code to get it to work, I think it would be more beneficial if you sit through a [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: "and we're not allowed to use global variables" Best instructor ever. Using globals as a habit is easy to pick up, hard to break, and pretty bad in general.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to define functions here - just execute that code in the `if` statements, instead:

```
def menu(balance):
    print("1...Deposit\n2...Withdraw\n3...View Balance")
    userChoice = int(input("Please enter your choice now: "))
    if userChoice == 1:
        deposit = float(input("Please enter the amount you would like to deposit: "))
        balance = balance + deposit
    elif userChoice == 2:
        withdraw = float(input("Please enter the amount you would like to withdraw: "))
        balance = balance + withdraw
    else:
        print("Your balance is", balance)
    return balance

...
balance = 0
balance = menu(balance)
```

The reason nothing is happening is because, with the way your code is now, you're *defining* the functions but not *calling* them. Look at your indentation - the calls to `withdraw()`, `deposit()`, and `balance()` are only executed inside the `else` block. And without any arguments, to boot, which would cause an error if they were executed.

Comment: I changed it so I just called the functions within the if statement, but now it's saying that I'm missing the required argument balance in my functions. I'm not entirely sure how to pass it through all of the functions.

Comment: See what I'm doing in the example above with `balance = menu(balance)`? Do something like that: pass in a value, have the function do something with the value and spit out an updated version, and then overwrite the original with the newer value